# "CMU Serif" font is not found by fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

When I compile a document using the CMU Serif font:

```
%!TeX program = xelatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec} 
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{document}
```

I get an error: `Package fontspec: The font "CMU Serif" cannot be found`, even if the font is actually installed in `/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/cm-unicode/`.

I know that I can load the fond by giving a filename (several filenames with the variants), but why does `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` not work?

**EDIT :** Several topics here mention a `/.../fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf` file, but there is no such file on my computer. I have no idea whether it is related to my problem, so i just mention it.

Comment: have you tried `lualatex` instead of `xelatex`? `xelatex` is motoriously crankry about where it looks for fonts. I cannot get it to use texlive fonts on my Linux box. No issues what so ever with `lualatex`

Comment: linux systems need additional fontconfig setup if you want to call fonts by font name, see https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-330003.4.4

Comment: On my system that config file lives in `/opt/texlive/2021/texmf-var/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf`. From the PATH you gave it seems you are using a TeXLive from a Linux dist. No idea if they include `texlive-fontconfig.conf`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer see my EDIT : maybe is this the cause of my problem?

Comment: @daleif there is no result when I run `locate fontconfig.conf`, so there is realy no such file on my system. ;-)

Comment: It it not called `fontconfig.conf`, it's `texlive-fontconfig.conf`

Comment: @daleif I know, it doesn't change anything: the file is not here.

Comment: I had a look via `apt-file`, `texlive-fontconfig.conf` does not seem to be in any of the texlive Ubuntu packages. Yet another reason why I never use LaTeX from a Linux dist.

Comment: Interesting thing is that I can find this file in upstream TeXLive 2015 until and inclusing 2021. (2015 is the oldest one I have on my system). So Ubuntu/Debian/whoever repackaged it never seemed to include it.

Comment: I'm on windows, I can't help you with concrete steps. I can only tell you that you need to extend your fontconfig setup if you want to use fonts from the texmf tree by name.

Comment: please don't change the question title (most questions get solved:-) just mark the question as answerd by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My setup is different than yours but you can probably adapt it. My version of `texlive-fontconfig.conf` has the following contents

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
  <dir>/opt/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype</dir>
  <dir>/opt/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype</dir>
  <dir>/opt/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/type1</dir>
</fontconfig>
```

You will need to adapt the first two `<dir>`'s to what fits your system. And it is recommended (David via chat) to delete the `type1` line.

Once you have that proceed as described in

https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-330003.4.4

that worked fine on my system, where `xelatex` normally cannot use the TL fonts.

That is I did:

```
sudo cp texlive-fontconfig.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive.conf 
sudo fc-cache -fsv
```

Comment: It works, thanks a lot!